# How to test the URL change if click on NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have the simple component as below:

```
<NavLink
          id="create-btn"
          to="/create"
        >
          Create
        </NavLink>
```

so, how can I test the URL after simulate the 'click' event on NavLink?
My testing as below, but it doesn't work

```
window.location.assign = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
wrapper.find('NavLink#create-btn').simulate('click');
expect(window.location.assign).toBeCalledWith('/create');
```

the result points out that `window.location.assign` is not called

Answer (score 1):

Simply this shouldn't be tested by yourself, but the third lib party has to make sure that this functionality is given at any time. So I guess you aren't forced to write test at all.